# Как отменить изменение ссылки при комментировании в Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, url, комментарии

При стандартных Вордпрессовских комментариях, когда оставляешь коммент и кликаешь на сабмит - изменяется урла.

Например:

Было вот так - http: // testsite / uncategorized / test-post-1 /

А становится вот так - http: // testsite / uncategorized / test-post-1 / # comment-1428

Или даже вот так: http: // testsite / uncategorized / test-post-1 /? Unapproved = 1246588 & moderation-hash = 40271ae6cdb307b9243b08107da795ae # comment-1246588

Подскажите пожалуйста, что нужно сделать, чтобы урла текущей страницы никогда не менялась при комментировании.

Там есть какое-то простое решение, или нужно аяксом это дело решать?
Спасибо.

Comment: 1. УРЛ - Uniform Resource Locator = Унифицированный **указатель** ресурса. "Он", а не "она". 2. Учи матчасть чтобы не забивать головы (себе и другим) подобной фингёй.

Comment: Если у кого-то мозг настолько закостенелый, что ума в нём не хватает на то, чтобы понять насколько гибок русский язык, то это уже не мои проблемы.
Тут нужно по делу отвечать, а не гадить в комментах...

Comment: Не надо оправдывать свою безграмотность гибкостью русского языка. Причем безграмотность не только в русском. За сим, хам неблагодарный, я откланиваюсь.

Comment: У тебя больше знаний и опыта, молодец. Но если ты решил, что это даёт тебе право смешивать с говном тех, кто знает и умеет меньше, то это полностью обесценивает тебя как личность и человека. Тем более stackoverflow создан для помощи другим, а не для галимого тролинга. Настигнет тебя карма, будешь знать!

Comment: Вот только не надо винить меня, если ты оказался в говне. Тебе, дураку, знания дают, а ты не способен их понять и только хамишь в ответ.

Comment: Вот такие знания ты мне дураку даёшь. Рассказал какого рода слово УРЛ и сказал учить матчасть...
"1. УРЛ - Uniform Resource Locator = Унифицированный указатель ресурса. "Он", а не "она". 
2. Учи матчасть чтобы не забивать головы (себе и другим) подобной фингёй."
Спасибо за знания, очень признателен. Главное ответил в тему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Быстро решить проблему с помощью кодинга не получилось, но выручил плагин wp ajaxify comments.